# Tensorflow: how to use Tile to duplicate rows of a Tensor object?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am completely new to Tensorflow. I have a tensor named "lebels" of shape (128,) and I want to change it to (128, 10) by using the `tf.tile` method.

I have tried,

```
tf.tile(labels, [10, 1])
```

However this gives me the error

> "Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'Tile' (op: 'Tile') with input shapes: [128], [2]"

I tried to search online but found nothing relevant. It looks like a easy thing to do but I have spent hours to try to get it working with no success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [replicate a row tensor using tf.tile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45315545/replicate-a-row-tensor-using-tf-tile)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the documentation of [tf.tile](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tile). It clearly says

`multiples: Length must be the same as the number of dimensions in input`

In your example, rank of `labels` is `1` and `len([10, 1]) == 2` which is why you are seeing the error.

You could try something like

`tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(labels, -1), [1, 10])`

or

`tf.tile(tf.reshape(a, [128, 1]), [1, 10])`