# How to form multiple layers tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

In tensorflow, I have a tensor of shape [2,3,3,1], now I would like to copy the tensor to multiple layer to tensor of shape [2,3,3,3], how can I do that?

Comment: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361467/tensorflow-numpy-repeat-alternative) is helpful

Comment: Also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45315545/replicate-a-row-tensor-using-tf-tile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with `tf.tile` or `tf.concat`:

```
t = tf.random_uniform([2, 3, 3, 1], 0, 1)
s1 = tf.tile(t, [1, 1, 1, 3])
s2 = tf.concat([t]*3, axis=-1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tnp, s1np, s2np = sess.run([t, s1, s2])
    print(tnp.shape)
    print(s1np.shape)
    print(s2np.shape)
```

which prints

```
(2, 3, 3, 1)
(2, 3, 3, 3)
(2, 3, 3, 3)
```

To illustrate what happens, may be it's easier to look at a 2d example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

t = tf.random_uniform([2, 1], 0, 1)
s1 = tf.tile(t, [1, 3])
s2 = tf.concat([t]*3, axis=-1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tnp, s1np, s2np = sess.run([t, s1, s2])
    print(tnp)
    print(s1np)
    print(s2np)
```

which prints

```
[[0.52104855]
 [0.95304275]]
[[0.52104855 0.52104855 0.52104855]
 [0.95304275 0.95304275 0.95304275]]
[[0.52104855 0.52104855 0.52104855]
 [0.95304275 0.95304275 0.95304275]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution if you want values for each duplicate generated by the same initializer (but not necessary the exact same values).

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.reset_default_graph()
init_shape = [2, 3, 3, 1]
n_times = 2
var1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=init_shape))
vars_ = [tf.contrib.copy_graph.copy_variable_to_graph(var1, var1.graph)
         for _ in range(n_times)] + [var1]

result = tf.reshape(tf.concat(vars_, axis=3),
                    shape=init_shape[:-1] + [len(vars_)])
print(result.get_shape().as_list())
# [2, 3, 3, 3]
```

Copy variables using `tf.contrib.copy_graph` and then concatenate them as in previous answer.